# Trying to remove an item from an array but it wont work

Tags: php, arrays

I dont really understand why this is not working, I am being returned to the correct header but the item is still in the array!

Here is the remove from array code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['username']) )
{
  header("Location:loginform.php");
  exit();
}

foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $disk)
{
  if (($_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn']) - ($_GET['bookisbn'])== 0)
  {
    unset($_SESSION['list'][$key]);
    break;
  }
}
header("Location: ".$_GET['location']);
exit();
?>
```

Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: You need to debug and test if line with unset is reachable.

Comment: two possibilities :
->you have got more than 1 key where your condition could be found but with your code only one is treated
->you do not remove the write key.

print `var_dump($_SESSION['list']);` before and after your loop.
if you've got an indexed array use array_splice to remove one entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a guess but the problem may lie in the fact that

```
$_GET['bookisbn']
```

is being treated as a string. Therefore if you cast it to an int 
the if statement will return true removing the item from the 
array.

Introduce this code:

```
// Casting the ISBN to an integer here
$bookISBN = (int) $_GET['bookisbn'];

if( ($_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn'] - $bookISBN) == 0 ) {
    // Unset item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try session_write_close() before the header. Perhaps is not saving.

You can also do this:

```
$mydata = $_SESSION['list'] ;

//do something with $mydata

$_SESSION['list'] = $mydata;
```

It will result in easier to read code, if you have other type of error, with this way you will not make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

I would listen to Artragis, but also try this:

You have parenthesis around each of the variables, but it's really the subtraction that has to equal zero. So, instead of:

```
if (($_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn']) - ($_GET['bookisbn'])== 0)
{
    unset($_SESSION['list'][$key]);
    break;
}
```

Try:

```
if (($_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn'] - $_GET['bookisbn']) == 0)
{
    unset($_SESSION['list'][$key]);
    break;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I would also cast both the Session and the GET variables as INTs, like one of the other posters mentioned, as well.

Answer (score -1):

### You need to debug and test if line with unset is reachable.

You need to debug means you need to verify every program's step and every variable.
You need to test if line with unset is reachable means you have to echo something at the point of unset:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $disk)
{
  var_dump("---\n",$_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn'],$_GET['bookisbn']);
  var_dump($_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn'] - $_GET['bookisbn']);
  var_dump($_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn'] - $_GET['bookisbn'] == 0);

  if ($_SESSION['list'][$key]['bookisbn'] - $_GET['bookisbn'] == 0)
  {
    unset($_SESSION['list'][$key]);
    var_dump($_SESSION['list']);
    break;
  }
}
//comment out header to prevent moving out of page
#header("Location: ".$_GET['location']);
exit();
```

run this code and see if any of the values are wrong or unexpected.